# RoR, app with multiple resources, picking last two from DB

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to create an app with two resources - football players and 'fights' between them. Fight should always be a thing between just two recently added players.
My plan is to have 2 controllers, one for players, one for fights. When fight starts, it goes to action create in FightsController.
The problem is, surnames of players won't be in params helper, because I won't be selecting them or typing their names in a form - it should happen automatically.

I plan to have their names on a main page and just a button "fight", which invokes create action.

So, my problem is - how can I pick them from database in an elegant way in FightsController? I can do something like create(User.last...) or something like that, but is there any better way?

Kind regards,

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps have their id's as parameters to the link?  Or the "Fight" button could be the button of a form, and you could have two hidden inputs with the data required.

I would not suggest using Model.last because there is a chance you will not get the desired result, as well as it's not very clear as to what's going on there.

Comment: Thank you for your tips, but I have another problem now, I was focusing on controller, but I'm not sure, how to retrieve two last players from DB to display them on my main page (so view is now the issue). You suggest form, but how to pass their ids?

Comment: Model.find(:all, order: 'id desc', limit: 2) will get the last two records

Comment: thank you. I started writing code and ran into something else. My action create in FightsController should create new Fight object from 2 users, am I right? Is it even possible to create one object from other model's instances?

Answer (score 0):

When selecting the two players, I would use the "Fight!" button as a form submission to the Fights#Create and pass the players ids. There I would have `player_1 = User.find_by_id(:id)` and `player_2 = User.find_by_id(:id_2)`.

Your Fight model should have `has_many :users`

Comment: Thank you for your tips, but I have another problem now, I was focusing on controller, but I'm not sure, how to retrieve two last players from DB to display them on my main page (so view is now the issue). You suggest form, but how to pass their ids?